# Avoid parentheses in path using XPath 1.0

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

The following XML structure represents a website with many articles. Every article contains, among many other things, date of its creation and possibly arbitrarily many dates of its modification. I want to get the **date of the last access** (either creation or last modification) **to every article** using XPath 1.0.

```
<website>
    <article>
        <date><strong>22.11.2017</strong></date>
        <edits>
            <edit><strong>17.12.2017</strong></edit>
        </edits>
    </article>
    <article>
        <date><strong>17.4.2016</strong></date>
        <edits></edits>
    </article>
    <article>
        <date><strong>3.5.2011</strong></date>
        <edits>
            <edit><strong>4.5.2011</strong></edit>
            <edit><strong>12.8.2012</strong></edit>
        </edits>
    </article>
    <article>
        <date><strong>12.2.2009</strong></date>
        <edits></edits>
    </article>
    <article>
        <date><strong>23.11.1987</strong></date>
        <edits>
            <edit><strong>3.4.2001</strong></edit>
            <edit><strong>11.5.2006</strong></edit>
            <edit><strong>13.9.2012</strong></edit>
        </edits>
    </article>
</website>
```

In other words, the expected output is:

```
<strong>17.12.2017</strong>
<strong>17.4.2016</strong>
<strong>12.8.2012</strong>
<strong>12.2.2009</strong>
<strong>13.9.2012</strong>
```

---

So far I've only created this path:

```
//article/*[self::date or self::edits/edit][last()]
```

that looks for `date` and nonempty `edits` nodes in every `article` and selects the latter one. But I don't know how to access the latest `strong` of every such selection and the naive `//strong[last()]` appended to the end of the path doesn't work.

I found a solution in XPath 2.0. Either of these paths should work, if I'm not mistaken:

```
//article/(*[self::date or self::edits/edit][last()]//strong)[last()]
//article/(*//strong)[last()]
```

Such use of parentheses within path is invalid in XPath 1.0 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath 1.0 expression

```
/website/article/descendant::strong[parent::date|parent::edit][last()]
```

Selects the nodes:

```
<strong>17.12.2017</strong>

<strong>17.4.2016</strong>

<strong>12.8.2012</strong>

<strong>12.2.2009</strong>

<strong>13.9.2012</strong>
```

Tested in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/56d8f7bc4b9c8c064fdad16f22469026

**Do note**: position predicates acts over the context list.

Comment: Very clever! Thank you. By the way, I always expected the abbreviated syntax to give the same results as the full one, yet now I realized that the path `/website/article//strong[parent::date|parent::edit][last()]` selects completely different nodes.

Comment: @Jeyekomon You are welcome. The abbreviated syntax will be expanded to `/child::website/child::article/descendant-or-self::node()/child::strong[position()=last()]` so, here `position()` refers to the `child` axe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple xpath to get your output.

```
//article/descendant-or-self::strong[last()]
```

Comment: Curious to know, if this solves the issue. Though I checked from end, just want to check with you as you might have the entire structure.

Comment: Also correct answer. You're using the same trick as Alejandro with the unabbreviated syntax which did not come to my mind. I was stuck to only abbreviated one which was clearly faulty and probably unsolvable that way. Alejandro's solution is a bit safer though because he included the test for parents. The `strong` node can be relatively frequent within the article.